# My code prints out garbage instead of the desired text

Tags: assembly, dos, dosbox, vga, x86-16

I'm using 16bit assembly to create a DOS program for educational purpose on how to program VGA, I wrote a code to write color to some pixels the prints a string, the code gone good with changing the pixels color, but when i try to print the string, it prints weird characters, allot of them
I'm using MASM 5.00 and Link 3.60 and running on DOSBox

This is my code

```
org 100h
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg         db      'Hello VGA','$'
.code
main proc
mov ax, 0                                
mov al, 013h                             
int 10h

mov ah, 02h                                  ;function code for setting cursor pos.
mov bh, 0                                    ;setting page number
mov dx, 0                                    ;setting dh, dl to row and column
int 10h

mov ah, 0ch                                 
mov al, 00001110b                    
mov cx, -1

ploop:
inc cx                                           ;x point pos.
mov dx, 0                                  ;y point pos.
int 10h
cmp cx, 9919
jne ploop
;keyboard services

mov ah, 00h                                 ;read key function code
int 16h             

;set cursor position
mov ah, 02h
mov bh, 0                                       ;Display page
mov dh, 04h                                 ;Row
mov dl, 00h                                 ;Column
int 10h

;print msg
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg
int 21h
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
main endp
        end main
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked fine to me. Try initializing the data segment manually, insert next two lines immediately after `.code` : `mov ax,@data  mov ds,ax` .

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez i totally forgot about initializing the data segment, and that was the error, thanks for notice

Comment: "No idea" guess: you are using DOS 21h in graphical mode, maybe your dosbox+dos has troubles to output chars in gfx mode? Can you try outputting some char with int 10h ah,9? It will probably result in same thing, but just to be sure. (I think the 21h calls the 10h anyway, so don't expect miracle) BTW `mov ax,0` `mov al,013h` = you know that this can be done with single `mov ax,13h`? If not, try to reread what is `ax` and `al`.  (EDIT: oh, that `ds` is very likely the problem).

Comment: @Ped7g yes it `DS` problem, i forgot to initialize the data sector and the error fixed after initializing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code and it worked fine to me. Try initializing the data segment manually, insert next two lines immediately after `.code` :

```
.code
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Someone suggested me that my comment was better as an answer.